# Как к дате прибавить дни в Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Имеется DataFrame дат. Нужно к столбцу времени прибавить 7 дней.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dates_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02']).reshape(2,1))
dates_2 = dates_1 + pd.Timedelta("7 day")
```

Появляется ошибка

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "Timedelta") to str
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конвертируйте строки в специальный тип для хранения дат:

```
dates_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02'], dtype='datetime64').reshape(2,1))
```